# Level of a node in a binary tree

Tags: c++, data-structures

**Why the level of a node is not printing? Level is increased after every call?Where is the problem in the code?**

```
int levelNode(struct Node* root,int a,int level){
    if(root==NULL){
        return 0;
    }
    if(root->key==a){
        return level;
    }
    levelNode(root->left,a,level+1);
    levelNode(root->right,a,level+1);
}
```

Comment: Maybe it doesn't print because there are no calls to a function that prints?

Comment: Recursive functions work exactly like non-recursive functions. Your function needs to always return something. A decent compiler should warn you about this.

Comment: As Krishna's answers points out, you're throwing away the result of any recursion. Turn up your compiler warnings to pedantic levels and enable treating all warnings as errors. That should fail the build, and tell you why: not all code paths in your `levelNode` function return the value promised in the declaration (an `int`) look at it long enough it should be obvious why.

Answer (score 1):

Should it be like

```
int levelNode(struct Node* root,int a,int level){
    int found;
    if(root==NULL){
        return 0;
    }

    if(root->key==a){
        return level;
    }

    found = levelNode(root->left,a,level+1);
    if (found != 0) return found;

    found = levelNode(root->right,a,level+1);
    if (found != 0) return found;

    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: What will happen when node is not null and node's data is not given to the given input a

Answer (score 0):

Awwww, soooo much recursion! Just wanted to point out that recursion is absolutely evil, and I personally avoid it wherever I can (actually, you can always avoid it).

Just to have an alternative solution here in this thread.
If your tree is sorted, you can simply do:

```
int levelNode(struct Node* root, int a)
{
    node *temp = root;
    int level = 0;
    while (temp != NULL)
    {
        if (temp->data == a)
            break;
        level ++;
        if (a > temp->data)
            temp = temp->right;
        else if (a < temp->data)
            temp = temp->left;
    }
    if (temp == NULL)
        return 0;
    if (temp->data == a)
        return level;
    return 0;
}
```

In case your tree is not sorted, you can adapt my code slightly to do a "proper" full blown BFS.

Something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <queue>
#include <map>

int levelNode(struct Node* root, int a)
{

    std::queue<Node*> stack;
    std::map<Node*, int> xmap;
    stack.push(root);
    xmap[root] = 0;


    while (!queue.empty())
    {
        Node* f = queue.front();
        if(f == NULL) return;

        queue.pop();

        if(f->data == a) return xmap[f];

        if(f->left){
            queue.push(f->left);
            xmap[f->left] = xmap[f]+1;
        }
        if(f->right){
            queue.push(f->right);
            xmap[f->right] = xmap[f]+1;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```